# TradingView Cannot use mutable variable as an argument for security function

Tags: pine-script

Request help！！！！

```
//@version=3
strategy("我的策略", shorttitle = "long stragegy", overlay = true)


Kumo_offset = input(26, title = "位移周期")

CK_offset = input(26, title = "延迟线位移周期")


Kumo_offset := Kumo_offset - 1

CK_offset :=  CK_offset + 1



four_h_l = security(tickerid, '240', close >  Kumo_Top[Kumo_offset])

four_h_s= security(tickerid, '240', close < Kumo_Bottom[Kumo_offset])
```

However, there was an error

Cannot use mutable variable as an argument for security function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a request for Kumo_Top, Kumo_Bottom and symbol's close (if need) using different securities:

```
//@version=3
strategy("我的策略", shorttitle = "long stragegy", overlay = true)


Kumo_offset = input(26, title = "位移周期")
CK_offset = input(26, title = "延迟线位移周期")


Kumo_offset := Kumo_offset - 1
CK_offset :=  CK_offset + 1

Kumo_Top = open - close / 2 // as an example
Kumo_Bottom = high - low * 4  // as an example
// top = close >  Kumo_Top[Kumo_offset]


four_h_l = security(tickerid, '240', Kumo_Top)
four_h_s= security(tickerid, '240', Kumo_Bottom)

four_h_l_close = security(tickerid, '240', close)    //if you need different close

plot(four_h_l_close[Kumo_offset] > four_h_l[Kumo_offset] ? 1 : 0, color=red)
plot(four_h_l_close[Kumo_offset] < four_h_s[Kumo_offset] ? 1 : 0, color=green)
```